# Should the [Team-Motivation] and [Motivation] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

17 questions - [team-motivation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-motivation)

8 questions - [motivation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motivation)

Should these two tags be merged?  If not, what makes the two tags different?  If we merge them, is team-motivation the tag we should use, or should we use motivation as it seems more broad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basing on questions with these tags I'd say they're slightly different but just slightly. I'd vote for merging tags to a single "motivation" tag, as this one has broader meaning.

Comment: +1 agree, they are about the same subject